# How to backup table data to a simple text file using SQL query in sqlplus

Tags: oracle

I have tried to load data following:

```
create table emp_data (fname varchar2(20), lname varchar2(20))

orgaization external(type oracle_loader default directory dir1
access parameters( records delimited by newline
NOBADFILES NOLOGFILES fields terminated by ','
(fname char,lname char))
location('t1.txt'))
parallel 5
reject 200;
```

I am learning SQL. i learn how to upload data from a text file to the database using ORACLE_LOADER, but i want to simultaneously back up my data from tables into a simple text file.

How to back up data from particular table on a simple text file using SQL in sqlplus environment (RED HAT)?

Comment: You cannot user `ORACLE_LOADER` to unload data.

Answer (score 0):

If you really have to use SQLPLUS for the export, best way would be:

```
SQL> spool on
SQL> spool emp.txt
SQL> select * from emp_data;
SQL> spool out
```

However, Oracle has tools dedicated to data export such as expdp/impdp (data pump) in 10g